# Joint PDF of min and max of iid uniform distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

$U_1$ and $U_2$ are identically independently distributed ~uni[0,1].  I'm trying to find the joint PDF between the $P_1$=min($U_1$, $U_2$) and $P_2$=max($U_1$, $U_2$).  I have found the marginal pdfs:

$f_{p1}(y)=2y^2-4y+2$

$f_{p2}(x)=2x$

Since the min and max are not independent, I think the best course of action would be to find the conditional probability by conditioning on $U_1$ and then multiplying by the pdf of $U_1$. 
$$\int_0^1 P(min(U_1, U_2)<p_{1} ,P(max(U_1, U_2)<p_{2}\ \ |\ \  U_1=u)\ f_u(u)  \;\mathrm{dx}$$

However, I am stuck now.

Answer (score 1):

Going back to the cdf is always an option (and I don't believe your marginal pdf for $P_1$ as it doesn't integrate to 1).

We have, for $0\leq p_1\leq p_2\leq 1$
$$
\begin{align*}
F_{P_1,P_2}(p_1,p_2)&=\mathbb{P}(P_1\leq p_1, P_2\leq P_2)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(\min(U_1,U_2)\leq p_1,\max(U_1,U_2)\leq p_2)\\
&=\mathbb{P}((U_1,U_2)\in[0,p_1]\times[0,p_2]\cup[0,p_2]\times[0,p_1])\\
&=\mathbb{P}((U_1,U_2)\in[0,p_1]\times[0,p_2]\amalg(p_1,p_2]\times[0,p_1])\\
&=2p_1p_2-p_1^2
\end{align*}
$$
so differentiating gives the pdf
$$
f_{P_1,P_2}(p_1,p_2)=\frac{\partial^2 F_{P_1,P_2}(p_1,p_2)}{\partial p_1\partial p_2}=
\begin{cases}
2&\text{if }0<p_1<p_2<1\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$